# What type of logic should be in a controller? (MVC and Repository pattern)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I hear many opinions but is there a general rule as to what type of logic should be in a controller or not?

I use repositories for data access and updating but what about taking in model parameters in an action method updating it in the controller (from say, a FormCollection object etc), then passing it to a repository for updating.

Are there any definite no-no's?

Thanks

Comment: No. There's a lot of debate. The most sensible one is between skinny Controller vs Skinny Models. No other debates I can get behind. Google Skinny Controllers for more info. My advice is to move this to the Programmers Forum of Stack Exchange. They will be more receptive of it.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a google around, heard of skinny controllers before

Answer (score 4):

I usually design the Controller in a way that allows decoupling between the Model and the View, so that they can ignore the existence of each other.

The problem is defining what are the responsibilities of the Model, and what are the responsibility of the Controller with respect to those issues that are *borderline*. Nobody would argue that persisting an entity into the DB is a task for the Controller, but if for example we talk about validation, things get more controversial.

For the input validation, my personal approach is to perform it on the Controller side, with the assumption/constraint that entities are already valid when passed to the model. This trend is encouraged by some MVC frameworks (i.e. Struts) that provide out-of-the-box validation on the controller side, but may come short when, for example, you have to re-deploy your Model in a different context (e.g. a web service) and your validation rules are wired in the former Controller.

I encourage your research but with a small advice coming from personal experience: avoid thinking too much about it. This kind of issues are bloated by religious wars and pointless stubbornness of the advocates of the different approaches. In the real world, at the very end, all these design issues are messed up by the hard facts and you will just be asked to do something working in 15 minutes, as the VP wants it before lunch time.